# Python input() already filled after calling it

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Example:
I pressed the "K" key on my keyboard, that open's an input(). The problem is that the input() is already filled with the key I just pressed. It does this when I type more letters too.

The simplified code:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("K"):
        _input = input("> ")
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

I tried this:

```
_input = ""
_input = input("> ")
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Can't you just remove the `K` after reading the input?

Answer (score 0):

I can't check it right now, but it seems you can do something like this:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("K"):
        keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
        input()
        _input = input("> ")
```